# How to get screen changed event in Qt widget

Tags: qt, multiscreen

In my Qt application, I have couple of QtWidgets which are floating. I want to know when QtWidget is dragged to another screen So that I can resize content within according to new screen DPI.

Comment: What about querying `QDesktopWidget::screenNumber()` periodically?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Listened to event void QWindow::screenChanged(QScreen *screen)

Answer (score 0):

Connect the [`primaryScreenChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop) signal from your `QGuiApplication` to slots in your widgets.

**Edited to add:** On reflection, this probably doesn't do what you want -- it signals when the *application* changes screen, not the widget.

Comment: One Query, My application has lot of QDialogs, so this signal is emitted. only one Qdialog is moved other screen not main application window.

Comment: I have DISPLAY1 and DISPLAY2, DISPLAY1 is primary, when DISPLAY1 HDMI is plug out,  after primaryScreenChanged signal, MainWindow is shown on secondary screen DISPLAY2, but MainWindow->screen() is still DISPLAY1.